# Is it possible that a PHP script will be interrupted?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script on a web server that does this:

1. Receives file upload
2. Saves file upload
3. Records upload to database

I would like actions 2 and 3 to occur atomically. There should be no scenario where 2 happens and 3 does not.

PHP scripts can time out. But are there other situations where the script could get interrupted? Can I prevent those?

Comment: The database is a separate service on your server, a communication error can always occur. To prevent uplouds without being saved make sure you check the affected rows by your database if that is 0 then unlink the file. Also make sure the max post size and max upload file are set correct, if the file is larger then those settings the file wont reach your script

Comment: As noted, you don't prevent these, you guard against them. A power cord could literally be pulled out of a server right after step #2. You need a step #4, "Mark entry as good" (or whatever) and the entry should start out as "Not good". Optionally, add a third status of "In progress" so that in the future you can audit if/when this happens.

Comment: Server / (webserver / fpm) could be restarted.

Comment: Use the db to your advantage :  start by initating a transaction, then write your DB stuff, then move your files, then commit if no error occured.  not 100 % garantied atomicity, but close.  Also, if you upload to a file system, and for the final 'save' you move the fiile to somewhere else in the same file system, THAT move is atomic (no copy involved).   But again, multiple sub-systems involved, you have to deal with possible errors.

Comment: I understand that power pulls and server restarts will always interrupt my script. Are there OTHER situations which I CAN prevent at the PHP level?